# Strange Overlay Icons Visual Studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

[image: Weird Overlay Icons]

I downloaded a project off codeproject and was messing around with it (I am more an asp.net developer) when I noticed these overlay icons...the lock one on the label is really interesting as when I right click the control is unlocked yet all the properties are grayed out.  When I add a new label I do not have that lock icon when I select it.  What is this?  Also what is the double boxes icon (the other 8 that are highlighted)?

Comment: I've never seen that flashing box icon, so I'm not putting it as an answer, but when I've seen that lock icon and behavior, it generally means the form is inheriting from another form, and that the control came from that form, so you should edit it there.

Comment: Perhaps the creator of the project on CodeProject could give you some more indepth insight on the issue

Comment: Thank you...I was not familiar with inherited forms!  I added a field to the base class and it added it on all the inherited forms when I built the project.  Thank you a lot @neminen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Winforms designer observes standard .NET accessibility keywords.  The *Modifiers* keyword for a control is what counts here.  That sets the access keyword for the member variable.  The default for a C# project is *private*, for a VB.NET project it is *Friend*.  VB.NET is more friendly about it.

That matters when you derive a form from a base form, Project + Add New Item, Windows Forms node, Inherited Form item template.  The derived form will have the controls of the base form but they cannot be changed if their Modifiers property is Private.  The designer makes it obvious by displaying the lock icon.  And by displaying the properties of the control in gray text.

Comment: how can I remove it? i have changed the base form modifier to public, but I am still getting the "highlighted(above)" box icon

Answer (score 0):

Normally this means that the controls are defined in the base control and so you cannot change them in the derived control (so they are all locked).